# How to use case statement with Partition by clause and avoid Group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to avoid the group by clause when using a case and partition by. Is that feasible? I keep sum(case ...) to avoid group by and it throws window function not allowed.

```
        select DISTINCT
        a.CIF
       ,a.accnt
     --,a.prod --how to avoid
        ,case when prod='dbal' then SUM(BAL) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ACCNT) end as ACCNT_bal
        ,case when prod='cbal' then SUM(BAL) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ACCNT) end as CREDIT_bal
    ---  ,SUM(case when prod='dbal' then SUM(BAL) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ACCNT) end) as ACCNT_bal
     ---   ,SUM(case when prod='cbal' then SUM(BAL) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ACCNT) end) as CREDIT_bal
        from q2.accnt a 
        join balance d on a.id=d.id
        where date=20230709
        AND prod in( 'dbal', 'cbal') 
        group by a.CIF, a.accnt --,a.pord
```

I am getting the following error when the above is used.

> ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here
> 30483. 00000 -  "window  functions are not allowed here"
> *Cause:    Window functions are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query.
> And, window function cannot be an argument to another window or group
> function.
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 3 Column: 38

Comment: When using window functions, why would you use also group by in the very same select? If you group by, then you no longer use over(partition by...). Or, if you wish to group by after using window functions, then use common-table-expression. Not sure what you wish to achieve.

Comment: I dont want to use group by. the query is complaining abt missing group by clause

Comment: Do you really want to add up the balances across different CIFs?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `OVER` logic and use a normal aggregate, placing the case logic inside `SUM()`:

```
select a.CIF
       ,a.accnt
       ,SUM(case when prod='dbal' then BAL end) as ACCNT_bal
       ,SUM(case when prod='cbal' then BAL end) as CREDIT_bal
  from q2.accnt a 
  join balance d on a.id=d.id
  where date=20230709
   AND prod in( 'dbal', 'cbal') 
  group by a.CIF, a.accnt
```

If you really want to aggregate those balances *across* `CIF` values (be sure this is really what you want, it will show you the same balance for every row of the same `acct`), you can wrap that `SUM` in another windowed `SUM`.

```
select a.CIF
     ,a.accnt
     ,SUM(SUM(case when prod='dbal' then BAL end) OVER (PARTITION BY accnt) as ACCNT_bal
     ,SUM(SUM(case when prod='cbal' then BAL end) OVER (PARTITION BY accnt) as CREDIT_bal
from q2.accnt a 
join balance d on a.id=d.id
where date=20230709
 AND prod in( 'dbal', 'cbal') 
group by a.CIF, a.accnt
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to aggregate the balances both prod in( 'dbal', 'cbal')  across Accnt numbers NOT at CIF. Ex: we have same Accnts with dbal and cbal and I wanted to sum them but at Accnt level. Please advise

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your code and mine both limit the aggregation to within account numbers, but you're now saying you want to aggregate *across* account numbers which is something different. Maybe you can give an example?